# windows server 2012 cpu quota

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cpu-usage, multi-threading

I have written a multi-threaded program that is running on Windows server 2012.
The program will create threads to take advantage of multiple CPUs and I can control the number of simultaneous threads it will create.  Each thread will normally use 100% of a CPU for several minutes (it is a very CPU intensive calculation and no I/O is done).  Over the life of the process it will create and destroy ~1000 threads.

Task Manager reports that the server has 10 cores and 20 logical processors.  I have tried many settings for the number of simultaneous threads, but the CPU utilization as shown from task manager never goes above ~30%.  When I look at each thread, none is using more than ~3% total CPU - when they should be using 100%.

Another point to note: if I run two of these processes at the same time each will use ~30% of the available CPU.

I have run the same program on my 4-core Windows 10 laptop and have no problem with it using all the CPU.

Can anyone see a reason why Windows Server 2012 would limit my process to ~30% of the total CPU available?

Comment: One thing I have tried is setting [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Quota System] "EnableCpuQuota"=dword:00000000 and rebooting.  Did not make any difference.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Interactive or scheduled task? Command prompt application or Windows application? Have you tried running it from the console session?

Comment: It is a console app.  I have tried both interactive and scheduled task.  Ultimately it will run as a scheduled task.  Not quite sure what you mean by "from the console session" - do you mean interactively from the command prompt? - if so, yes I have tried this.  None of these variations have made a difference in CPU usage.

Comment: `mstsc /admin` connects to a console session.

Comment: Ah - sorry.  I think I see what you are asking: am I running the program from a Remote Desktop session on the server?  Yes, when I run it interactively my session is via Remote Desktop (I am using ASG RemoteDesktop).  And I am an administrator.